# ValueError: shapes (2,100) and (2,1) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am doing a machine learning homework and I am making the Logistic Regression Descent Gradient and Logistic Regression Cost. 
My functions are like this:

```
def calcLogRegressionCost(X, y, theta):
    #X is the feature vector
    #Y is the target vector/ output vector
    #theta is the weight vector 

    observations = len(y)
    predictions = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta))

    #Take the error when label=1
    class1_cost = -y*np.log(predictions)

    #Take the error when label=0
    class2_cost = (1-y)*np.log(1-predictions)

    #Take the sum of both costs
    cost = class1_cost + class2_cost

    #Take the average cost
    cost = cost.sum() / observations

    return cost



def logRegressionGradientDescent(X, y, theta0, alpha):
    #X is the feature vector
    #Y is the target vector/ output vector
    #theta0 is the weight vector 
    #alpha is the learning rate
    #iteration is the steps you want to take 
    #Start you code from here\


    N = len(X)

    #1 - Get Predictions
    predictions = sigmoid(np.dot(X, theta0))

    #2 Transpose features from (100, 2) to (2, 100)
    # So we can multiply w the (100,1)  cost matrix.
    # Returns a (2,1) matrix holding 3 partial derivatives --
    # one for each feature -- representing the aggregate
    # slope of the cost function across all observations
    gradient = np.dot(X.T,  predictions - y)

    #3 Take the average cost derivative for each feature
    gradient /= N

    #4 - Multiply the gradient by our learning rate
    gradient *= lr

    #5 - Subtract from our weights to minimize cost
    weights -= gradient

    #you should return theta or loss or the both depending on your way
    #of implementation

    return weights
```

They ask me to run the Gradient Descent Algorith to fit my parameters theta to my training set. I did a train function which is the following:

```
W1 = 0.0
W2 = 0.0
weights = np.array([
    [W1],
    [W2]
])


def train(features, labels, weights, lr, iters):
    cost_history = []

    for i in range(iters):
        weights = logRegressionGradientDescent(features, labels, weights, lr)

        #Calculate error for auditing purposes
        cost = cost_function(features, labels, weights)
        cost_history.append(cost)

        # Log Progress
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print ("iter: " +str(i) + " cost: "+str(cost))

    return weights, cost_history


train([data['First Exam Score'], data['Second Exam Score']], data['Admitted'], weights, 0.00001, 1000)
```

When I call the function train with my data, it gives me the following error:

ValueError: shapes (2,100) and (2,1) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)

I am not sure how to make the parameters fit with my dataset. The dataset is a 100 x 3 dataframe. The first 2 columns are data about the grades 100 students obtained in the First and Second Exam respetively. The third columns shows whether they got admitted or not in their desired university, depending on their grades. It is represented by 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

> When I call the function train with my data, it gives me the following
>   error:
>
> ValueError: shapes (2,100) and (2,1) not aligned: 100 (dim 1) != 2
>   (dim 0)

One thing that you must remember as a programmer is that error messages are invaluable for debugging. They give you valuable information about where your logic or code is prone to failure, or is already failing.
If you read the error message, you can note the following things:

1. As the error mentions *misaligned shapes*, and we know shapes are associated with *vectors and matrices*, the problem seems to be related to dimensions of feature matrix and weight matrix being passed into your logistic regression function.
2. Error message mentions misalignment, which indicates problem possibly with *matrix multiplication* because misaligned matrices are expected to throw this error if the dimensions of the matrices are not compatible for multiplication or the order in which they are being multiplied leaves the operation infeasible.

By now, you probably would have realized that the error is pointing towards the Numpy dot product of the feature matrix **X** and the weight vector **θ**.
In order to fix this error, you will have to ensure two things: shapes of matrices are compatible for carrying out matrix multiplication, and the order of multiplication is correct. Remember that in logistic regression, you need one scalar output for each observation in the feature matrix, which can be further passed as an argument into a probability mapping like `sigmoid` function to give you the probability of that certain instance belonging to a given class.

**Solution to error**

To solve this problem, *transpose the feature matrix **X*** so that its shape changes to (100,2). After taking the transpose of the feature matrix, the dot product should become feasible, consequently solving the error you are encountering.

It is recommended to create a separate feature matrix, matrix **X**, which contains only the feature columns and not the target column, which is the last column in your data. It is also recommended to create a label vector **y**, which stores only the labels or target class column. If I was doing this, I would be doing everything in Pandas but since you are working with Numpy, here's how you can do it.

```
X = np.transpose([(data['First Exam Score'], data['Second Exam Score']]) #Reshapes the feature matrix from (2,100) to (100,2)
y = data['Admitted']

train(X, y, weights, 0.00001, 1000)
```

As you can notice, code becomes more readable this way and chances of encountering errors is reduced.
Hope this helps.